# Magento 2.2.2: Customer Grid Indexer not working

Tags: magento2.2.2, reindex, customer-grid

While re indexing got an error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source::addAttributeToSelect() in /var/www/html/ncsmokehouse/vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/Handler/AttributeHandler.php:38

Comment: Did you done any modifications or added any custom module?

Comment: yes add this function 
public function addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias = null)
    {
       $this->customerCollection->addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias);
       return $this;
   }

Comment: i follow this link
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10838
but  my error got not remove

Comment: Where did you add it? Can you update your code with module files as well?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10838#issuecomment-360065531  this one

Comment: in this path 
app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Indexer/Source.php

source.php file code is 

app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Indexer/Source.php

just add this function in core source.php file 

    public function addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias = null)
    {
       $this->customerCollection->addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias);
       return $this;
   }

Comment: Can you add it in vendor file? Or you need to override it into your custom module and test again.

Comment: @AmitBera i want to add these change in app code folder ..
in vendor how can i push on magneto cloud server ?
vendor folder is write protected .

Comment: @SukumarGorai i overriede it my custom module . every thing is fine , reindexing done . but then  got an another issue  in admin site Wysywig editor shows broken image icons .?

Comment: I dont't think Wysywig issue is related to this issue.

Comment: i actually want to resolve my broken image icons .. when i remove my custom module then broken image issue resolve and re indexing  issue face .? how can i resolve both issues

Comment: @SukumarGorai i test Wyswing issue is related to this module overriding issue. coz when i remove my custom module folder and relaunch the project .broken image removed and images are shown

Comment: Did you override anything else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83310/discussion-between-hafiz-arslan-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: here i my overrides module for customer re indexing

https://github.com/hafizjee/fix-customer-grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a function :

```
public function addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias = null)
    {
       $this->customerCollection->addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias);
       return $this;
   }
```

in this file 
**/www/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Indexer/Source.php**

you can override this file because we can't change in core module.
it's working

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it works. However, after that, I've found another reindex issue, which I've solved by following this [Magento 2 How to Unlock Reindex Process: Index is locked by another reindex process Skipping](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/unlock-reindex-process-magento-2.html)